# Is there a way in python to take a list and convert it to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
([“name”, “jack”],[“job”, “doctor])
```

that I want to turn into a dictionary any help?

I want to create a function that takes the list and makes it a dictionary rather then having to retype it.

Output should be {“name”:“Jack”, “job”: “doctor”}

Comment: What would the dictionary be? By the way you have tuple, not a list.

Comment: Yes. The `dict` constructor will do exactly this to an iterable of pairs.

Comment: 1) This is not a list, 2) What is the expected output?

Comment: Output should be {“name”:“Jack”, “job”: “doctor”}